# How does clearing full rows work in tetris?

Tags: tetris

I'm working on my tetris game, and I'm a bit confused on the aftermath of clearing a full row. In some implementations, clearing a row, shifts all the rows above it down one row. That's how I originally envisioned implementing it, but I don't think it's quite that simple.

e.g., let's take a look at this video starting at [33:34](https://youtu.be/8OK8_tHeCIA?t=2024)

You can see that the L piece (full of Fs) is dropping down and it forms a full row which gets cleared, and then all the rows above it are shifted downwards by 1. However, I don't think this is quite correct because you end up with "floating" pieces, e.g., take a look at the 4th row from the bottom "A GF   G#". The first G is floating in space. Shouldn't it be translated all the way down to fill the gap? This makes the this functionality a bit more complicated to implement but feels more correct to me.

Comment: It works as the creator of the game did it. If in your game it should shift down, it will shift down. If they should float, they will float.

Comment: @Zibelas Do you know how it works in classical tetris games? I was trying to simulate it by playing a real game but couldn't get the exact scenario to form (admittedly I only tried for 5 mintes)

Comment: It is your game, you also take the role of designer, you decide the mechanics. Deciding they will be a clone of another game is an option. But if you are going by "some implementations", you need to make a decision on any situation when they don't agree. About the original game, if I recall correctly it does the simple version. With that said, if the question is strictly how did the original game work, I think that belongs in https://gaming.stackexchange.com - If you want help deciding, we need to know your goal or criteria. Yet, you seem to know what you want, do your "more correct" version.

Answer (score 2):

Again, it works however the game designer defines it. [Line clear gravity](https://tetris.wiki/Line_clear#Line_clear_gravity) varies by implementation and sometimes the game mode. The video you linked appears to be using naive gravity as it leaves floating unconnected blocks after a line clear:

[image: naive line clear example]

The alternative you describe sounds like [cascade mode](https://tetris.wiki/Cascade_mode) gravity:

[image: cascade mode gravity]

as the system is recursive - it clears the line and then reapplies gravity to check for subsequent line clears.

The [sticky mode variant](https://tetris.fandom.com/wiki/Tetris_Worlds#Sticky_mode) modifies this further by using color coding to change both the gravity and clearing rules. Sticky includes some multi-colored pieces which break into smaller pieces of separate colors when they lock. Blocks of the same color glue themselves together; any contiguous group of the same color with 25 or more blocks disappears. Anything with nothing supporting it falls, just as in cascade mode.

Naive gravity is easer to code and limits player strategy with respect to field management. Other modes typically more complex and provide the player with more options. For instance the naive gravity example is a favorable option with cascade gravity as it will result in a subsequent line clear.

Variations allow us to tune the play experience by making design choices. For instance, allowing cascades provides a wider move set to the player and rewarding cascade chains incentives certain types of play.

There are [many variants of Tetris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tetris_variants). Which is 'correct' depends on your design priorities (type of play are you favoring) and constraints (resources required to build/test/maintain a more complex system).

Comment: It's not super clear to me how sticky gravity and cascade mode differ in these examples. Both show a number of islands falling as far as they can individually, simultaneously, followed by line clears for any new lines formed. Is there a subtlety I'm missing, or an example that would illustrate the difference more starkly?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for pointing that out. I agree that the visual example for sticky doesn't really illustrate a difference from cascade. I couldn't find a better illustration, so I pulled the pic & described it verbally instead.

Comment: Thank you; that does clarify it. I might have cause to use this in a design exercise with my students, so maybe I'll whip up a diagram in the process. 